# NHibernate.Search Projections

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate.search

How-to use NHibernate.Search Projections ?

Answer (score 0):

see here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en/html/search-query.html#projections